# Remove item from list in Pybind

Tags: pybind11

I am moving CPython calls to pybind. I had the following code:

```
PyObject* my_list = ...;
PyList_SetSlice(my_list , i, i+1, NULL);
```

Which was used to remove an item. Now, switching to pybind11, I have

```
py::list my_list = ...;
```

And I would like to write something like

```
my_list.pop(i);
```

But I didn't find anything to do that. What should I do? Is the following correct:

```
PyList_SetSlice(my_list.ptr() , i, i+1, NULL);
```

Or am I leaking the object `my_list[i]`?

Comment: not sure if this is why, but `my_list.remove(i)` will remove the element `i` from the list -- it's not an index for which element to remove.  So if `my_list = ["hello", "world"]` you'd have to do `my_list.remove("hello")`, not `my_list.remove(0)`.  you can use `my_list.pop(0)` if you need to do it by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you don't advocate the syntax in @oooyaya's suggestion, but one way to remove an element at a specified `index` of the list would be to use `pop()` like

```
my_list.attr("pop")(index);
```

Comment: Actually the syntax of @oooyaya was fine, and I edited the post to reflect on that. I didn't know this `attr` feature to call any Python code. Still I would have prefered a `pop` method inside the C++ `py::list`, but I guess I can ask for it on the PyBind11 GitHub repo

Comment: Oh yeah I see. Indeed, the `py::list` instances are still python objects. I guess it wouldn't be trivial to have a C++ equivalent. If your python lists contain objects of the same type, you can use `std::vector<type>` instead.